How to plot the image of the unit disc under the mapping $f(z)=z/(1-z)$
I have plotted the image of the disk of $e^{re^{I t}} $like this:
ParametricPlot[ {Re[Exp[ r Exp[I t]]],Im[Exp[rExp[I t]]]}, {r,0,1},{t,0,2 Pi},AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}, Frame -> False]
But unable to plot the image of the unit disk of the function $\frac{z}{1-z}$ using the parametric plot
ParametricPlot[{(rExp[I t])/(1-r Exp[I t]), (r Exp[I t])/(1-r Exp[I t])}, {t, 0, 2 Pi}, {r, 0, 1}]

You're missing the Re and Im, the same you have in your first example.

The transformed region is infinite, so it cannot literally be plotted. For instance, TransformedRegion[] does not solve this problem. -- Another typo: rExp should have a space after the r in the second code.

Oops, the typo rExp appears in the first code, too.

The problem consists indeed of a couple of simple typos, but here's a workflow that is pleasing to me, which makes me want to share anyway.
f = z |-> z/(1 - z);
ParametricPlot[r Exp[I t] // f // ReIm
 , {t, 0, 2 Pi}, {r, 0, 1}
 , Mesh -> {11, 9}] (* 11+1 divisions of the polar angle
                        9+1 divisions of the radial coordinate range *)



Slick!  Can add PlotPoints->100 to smooth contours.

This can be done with ComplexRegionPlot as follows.
f[z_] := z/(1 - z);
disk[z_] := Abs[z] <= 1
{ComplexRegionPlot[disk[z], {z, -3 - 3  I, 3 + 3  I}, PlotLabel -> z],
ComplexRegionPlot[disk[InverseFunction[f][z]], {z, -3 - 3  I, 3 + 3  I}, 
PlotLabel -> f[z]]}

{}

SetAttributes[g, {NumericFunction, Listable}]

 g[r_, \[Phi]_] = 
   Through[{Re, Im}[  (r E^(I \[Phi]))  /  (1 - r E^(I \[Phi]))]]

$$\left\{\ \Re\left(\frac{r \cos (\phi )+ i r \sin (\phi )}
{-i r \sin (\phi )-r \cos (\phi )+1}\right),
\quad \Im\left(\frac{r \cos (\phi )+i r \sin (\phi )}
    {-i r \sin (\phi )-r \cos (\phi )+1}\right)\ \right\}$$
 SetOptions[ ParametricPlot, 
   {ImageSize -> Small, PlotStyle -> Thickness[0.006], 
    ColorFunction -> (Hue[#3] &)}, 
     PlotRange -> {{-1, 1.2}, {-1.3, 1.3}}];

  Show[{ParametricPlot[ g[{0.1, 0.4, 0.5, 0.8}, \[Phi]], 
                      {\[Phi], 0, 2 \[Pi]} ], 
        ParametricPlot[g[r, Range[0 , 2 \[Pi], \[Pi]/12] ], 
       {r, 0.01, 0.99}]}]


